# How to display the media title in a listview?

Tags: android, arraylist, media, android-contentprovider

How can I get media titles from COntentResolver. i tried but it no works, i want to display media titles in my listView .

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
if (cursor != null) {
      int ind = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
      do {
        String T = cursor.getString(ind);
        abcl.add(T);
        Log.i("SOngName", T);
      } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
```

but this gives me error of IndexOutOfBondsExceptions, my error logcat is

[please any one guide , thanks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ieBcQ.png)

Comment: MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE does not exist as a column with whatever ContentProvider you're querying.

Comment: sir i understand , can you guide me little more , is this is for displaying all videos titles in my device storage ?

Comment: Does MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE get you what you want?

Comment: You could also try putting it in the projection field of the query call as a String array if it doesn't work as a column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well first of all you should go for **Cursor Documentation in android** . it will tell you that after using the cursor is not null check; you have to move cursor to the start of first row on incoming result set.

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
if (cursor != null) {
if(cursor.MoveToFirst()){
      int ind = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
      do {
        String T = cursor.getString(ind);
        abcl.add(T);
        Log.i("SOngName", T);
      } while (cursor.moveToNext());
  }
}
```